# How to extract the characters after a forward slash using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

How can I extract the substring after a `/` and compare the extracted value against another file ?

```
cat file 

/abc|98357|
abc/aabb|023947|
xyz/0102|293847|
pqr/pqrst|29384|
9864/truse|253123|
```

expected output :-

```
abc|98357|
aabb|023947|
0102|293847|
pqrst|29384|
truse|253123|
```

And then compare col 1 of file 1 with another file :-

```
aabb
pqrst
truse
```

Comment: You've asked a few questions recently that got awk answers so I expect you have some idea how to use awk now - please [edit] your question to show your attempt to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'/' '{print $2}' file
```

produces your "expected output".

---

> And then compare col 1 of file 1 with another file.

If you mean, "only print matching lines in file2 that match the first column of your 'expected output'", then the answer could be

```
comm -12 <(awk -F'[/|]' '{print $2}' file | sort) <(sort file2)
```